# button postback messenger bot is not being recieved on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I've been a little bit struggling , I'v put the button payload as follows .. but it's not being transmitted to server ,

the message object

```
        let message = {
          "attachment":{
          "type" : "template",
          "payload" : {
              "template_type" : "generic",
              "elements" : [
              {
                "title" :  "title",
                "buttons": [{
                              "type": "postback",
                              "title": "wishlist",
                              "payload": "wishlist"
                          },
                  ],
                },
               ],
            }
          }
      }
```

and the sending function

```
function sendMessage(recipientId, message) {
  request({
   url: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
   qs: {access_token: process.env.PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN},
   method: "POST",
   sender_action :"typing_on",
   json: {
     recipient: {id: recipientId},
     message: message,
   }
}, function(error, response, body) {
     if (error) {
       console.log("Error sending message: " + response.error);
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: Any errors or log messages?

Comment: @TimWoocker actually this is what I'm facing , no POST response on logs

Comment: 2018-04-02T11:04:22.746336+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up

2018-04-02T11:04:23.884163+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=g-shop.herokuapp.com request_id=14f354e2-a0af-453a-a338-f28a6aa53d8d fwd="79.134.142.149" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=404 bytes=393 protocol=https

2018-04-02T11:04:23.850951+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=g-shop.herokuapp.com request_id=1f6a1df8-88d3-4845-bacd-d7e658309a05 fwd="79.134.142.149" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=71ms status=304 bytes=149 protocol=https

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send a sender_action and message in the same request, so the recipient is never receiving your message.

Comment: I've removed the sender_action but it's still not received , do you have any other solution

Comment: Are you getting anything in the error callback of the POST?

Comment: I'm not receiving the request at all , neither an error !